# How to match url case insensitively in django rest framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have this line in a `urls.py`

```
url(r'^(?i)(?P<datasource>[a-z]+)/$', views.OdbcConfigDatasourceDetail.as_view()),
```

The `(?i)` is supposed to make the regex case insensitive. I suspect it is in fact searching case-insensitively, but that it is passing the named group `datasource` with case intact, which then causes lookup to fail.

How can I either lowercase the named group or the lookup field before it gets passed?

Comment: in your view you could use something like datasource=datasource.lower()

Comment: @Jingo That gives me a NameError `NameError: name 'datasource' is not defined`. The view itself is derived `class OdbcConfigDatasourceDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):`.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out using the (excellent) Django Rest Framework documentation, specifically [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#creating-custom-mixins)

For example, if you need to lookup objects based on multiple fields in the URL conf, you could create a mixin class like the following:

```
 class MultipleFieldLookupMixin(object):
     """
     Apply this mixin to any view or viewset to get multiple field filtering
     based on a `lookup_fields` attribute, instead of the default single field filtering.
     """
     def get_object(self):
         queryset = self.get_queryset()             # Get the base queryset
         queryset = self.filter_queryset(queryset)  # Apply any filter backends
         filter = {}
         for field in self.lookup_fields:
             if self.kwargs[field]: # Ignore empty fields.
                 filter[field] = self.kwargs[field]
         return get_object_or_404(queryset, **filter)  # Lookup the object
```

You can then simply apply this mixin to a view or viewset anytime you need to apply the custom behavior.

```
 class RetrieveUserView(MultipleFieldLookupMixin, generics.RetrieveAPIView):
     queryset = User.objects.all()
     serializer_class = UserSerializer
     lookup_fields = ('account', 'username')
```

I added this code to my project

```
class CaseInsensitiveLookupMixin(object):
    """
    Stole majority of this mixin 
    from http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/
    """
    def get_object(self):
        queryset = self.get_queryset()             # Get the base queryset
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(queryset)  # Apply any filter backends
        filter = {self.lookup_field: self.kwargs[self.lookup_field].lower()}

        return get_object_or_404(queryset, **filter)  # Lookup the object
```

Had to add `from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404` to the top of that file, and change the detail view to `class OdbcConfigDatasourceDetail(CaseInsensitiveLookupMixin, generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):`

Props to the DRF team for their excellent docs.